# Prove that if $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

Could someone please help me correct my following proof?

> Prove that if $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$.

**Proof:** Let $G=\left \langle a \right \rangle$ with $|G|=n$. Define the relation $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_{n}\to G$ by $\phi(k)=a^{k}$ with $0\leq k<n$.

Well-defined: For $0\leq k_{1}<n$ and $0\leq k_{2}<n$, if $k_{1}=k_{2}$, then $\phi(k_{1})=a^{k_{1}}=a^{k_{2}}=\phi(k_{2})$.

Operation preserving: Since $\phi(k_{1}+k_{2})=a^{k_{1}+k_{2}}=a^{k_{1}}a^{k_{2}}=\phi(k_{1})\phi(k_{2})$, the operation is preserved.

One-to-one: For $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}_{n}$, let $m>n$ and assume $\phi(m)=\phi(n)$. Then $a^{m}=a^{n}$ or $a^{m-n}=e$. Then $m-n>0$.

> I am not sure how to prove that $m-n<0$. Is it due to $G$ being abelian?

Onto: $\phi$ is onto iff for all $a^{k}\in G$, there exists a $k\in \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ such that $\phi(k)=a^{k}$. By definition, $\phi$ is onto.

Answer (score 0):

When you write $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}_n$, the symbol $n$ has two distinct meanings. In order to prove that $\phi$  is ono-to-one, all it take is to prove that $\ker\phi=\{0\}$. But$$\phi(k)=e\iff a^k=e\iff k=0,$$since $\operatorname{ord}a=n$.

And since $\phi$ is one-to-one and both groups have $n$ elements, $\phi$ is surjective too.

Comment: Even better the converse argument, as surjectivity is already proven: both groups have $n$ elements, so it must be injective, too.

Comment: @Berci Indeed, that's a better approach.

Comment: This is an easier proof, but I didn't study kernal, so my instructor expects something else.

Comment: @numericalorange If $\phi(k)=\phi(k')$, with $0\leqslant k<k'$, then $a^k=a^{k'}$ and therefore $a^{k'-k}=e$. This is impossible, because $0<k'-k<n$.

Comment: @Berci Thank you, your comment is the most helpful. I will use your approach!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you, your comment is also very helpful for the other approach!